# OpenCV Python, watermark can't be seen on white backgrounds

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, watermark

I am trying to paste my watermark to white-backgrounded image:

```
watermark = cv2.imread(watermark_path)
watermark_ratio = round(image.shape[1]/8)       # calculating the ratio 
resized_watermark = cv2.resize(watermark, (watermark_ratio, round(watermark_ratio/2)), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)    # resizing watermark size

h_logo, w_logo, _ = resized_watermark.shape
h_img, w_img, _ = image.shape
top_y = h_img - h_logo
left_x = w_img - w_logo
bottom_y = h_img
right_x = w_img

destination = image[top_y:bottom_y, left_x:right_x]
result = cv2.addWeighted(destination, 1, resized_watermark, 0.5, 0)     # pasting watermark on original image
image[top_y:bottom_y, left_x:right_x] = result

cv2.imwrite(save_path, image)          # saving watermarked the image
```

But I can't see watermark on white-backgrounded images, and I think I have to play with parameters of **addWeighted** method. This happens:

Note: Watermark is pasted to the bottom right corner.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Solved:
[image: Fixed image]

Comment: You are assigning the highest weightage to `destination` which is white. White has the highest pixel intensity and will overwhelm the logo `resized_watermark`. You can try splitting the weights for both the images: `result = cv2.addWeighted(destination, 0.5, resized_watermark, 0.5, 0)` . This will not affect the final image `image`

Comment: Ohhh, thank you bro, I'll definitely try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by an incorrect usage of `cv2.addWeighted`, in thie line:

```
result = cv2.addWeighted(destination, 1, resized_watermark, 0.5, 0)
```

The **2nd parameter** (you set to 1) is the **weight of the first image**.

If you want a blend of **50-50** between the image and the watermark, you should change it to:

```
result = cv2.addWeighted(destination, 0.5, resized_watermark, 0.5, 0)
```

See the documentation: [`addWeighted`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gafafb2513349db3bcff51f54ee5592a19).
And a usage example: [Adding (blending) two images using OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/dc4/tutorial_adding_images.html).

Comment: Thank you brother, I'll do that. Appreciate your effort